# When input is focused do not disappear hoverable menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

recently I'm trying to make a hoverable login menu and what I want is that when the user clicks one of the inputs(id or password inputs) then make hoverable menu appear until the user clicks outside of the element.

**So, it might be a little complicated to understand so here is an example here:**
https://www.superonline.net

As ye can see, if you hover "Giriş" in the header, login box appears and when you unhover it disapears. What's more, when you click one of the inputs in the box then you can only disappear login box by clicking outside of the box, wonder how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to solve it with JQuery, when you hover the element to show, you're gonna have to fake a hover/focus with Jquery. Here's a code I had found to prevent this for a search bar. It's EXACTLY the same logic.

```
$('.top-search-bar').blur(function() {
 if(mousedownHappened){
    $('.top-search-bar').focus();
    mousedownHappened = false;
 }
 else{
    $('.top-search-bar').removeClass('top-sb-nb');
    $('.input-results').removeClass('r-displayed');
 }
});

var mousedownHappened = false;
 $('.input-results').mousedown(function() {
    mousedownHappened = true;
});
```